# php curl_multi_exec на https соединении

Tags: php, curl, https

не могу вызвать скрипт через curl_multi_exec - вываливается GateWay timeout

как вызываю:

```
set_time_limit(0);

      $common_counter=0;
      $ii=0;
      $counter = 0;
      $curl_arr = [];
      $master = curl_multi_init();
        while ($common_counter<10000) {
        $common_counter++;
        $ii++;
        if ($ii>=950) {
          $ii=0;

            $curl_arr[$counter]=curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$counter], CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.ru/send-notif/send_notifi.php");
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$counter], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            ///curl_setopt($curl_arr[$counter], CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$counter], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$counter], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$counter]);
            $counter++;    
        }
      }


      $counter++; 

      $active = null;
      do {
          $master_res = curl_multi_exec($master,$active);

          echo ' 1 :'. $master_res.' + active='.$active;

      } while($master_res == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);



      while ($active && $master_res == CURLM_OK) {
          // Wait for activity on any curl-connection
          if (curl_multi_select($master) != -1) {
              // Continue to exec until curl is ready to
              // give us more data
            usleep(100);
          }
              do {
                  $mrc = curl_multi_exec($master, $active);
                  echo ' 2 :'.$mrc;

              } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);

      }

      foreach ($curl_arr as $key ) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $key);
      }

      curl_multi_close($master);
```

зависает на первом цикле. Моя строка echo выдает 1 :0 + active=10
т.е. $master_res==0 всегда и 10 штук активных запросов

сам вызываемый скрипт:

```
    $to      = 'my@mail-example.ru';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $message = 'send_notification teest notif ' ;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo "1";
```

ошибок не дает никаких (или я не знаю где их получить), но и не работает.
Подскажите куда копать, я уже запарился.
Чувствую каких-то опций через curl_setopt не поставил, но не могу найти каких.

PHP Version 5.6.29-0+deb8u1
curl  7.38.0

Comment: Example.com - это куда вы пробуете соединится, или заменили на шаблон в целях приватности?

Comment: заменил, конечно. настоящий адрес там верный - напрямую,через строку адресную, он открывается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)`. Ошибки по дефолту в логах веб-сервера.